# React Component Not Loading?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, redux

I have made a header.js component in a separate file in React, and I'm trying to bring it into the Profile.js file, but it's not loading in the front-end.

I am not getting any errors.

Output:

[image]

Profile.js:

In this file I think it's not able to load the header component as it's only printing the data from the `if` loop, and in-spite of having data in the `else` part, it is skipping that.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import aboutinfo from './aboutinfo';
import userinfo from './userinfo';
import header from './header';

import {getProfileByName} from '../../actions/userprofileAction';

class Profile extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.match.params.profilename) {
      this.props.getProfileByName(this.props.match.params.profilename);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { profile, loading } = this.props.profile;
    let profileContent;

    if (profile === null || loading) {
      profileContent = <h3>loadinggg....</h3>;
    } else {
      profileContent = (
        <div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <Link to="/userprofile" className="btn btn-light mb-3 float-left">
                Back 
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6" />
          </div>
          <header/>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="profile">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">{profileContent}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Profile.propTypes = {
  getProfileByName: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  profile: state.profile
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProfileByName })(Profile);
```

header.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import isEmpty from '../../validation/is-empty';

class header extends Component {
  render() {
    const { profile } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <div className="card card-body bg-info text-white mb-3">

            <div className="text-center">
              <h1 className="display-4 text-center">{profile.user.name}</h1>
              <p className="lead text-center">
                {profile.status}{' '}
                {isEmpty(profile.company) ? null : (
                  <span>at {profile.company}</span>
                )}
              </p>
              {isEmpty(profile.location) ? null : <p>{profile.location}</p>}

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default header;
```

userprofileaction.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {GET_USERPROFILE,PROFILE_LOADING,GET_ERRORS,CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE,GET_PROFILES} from './types';

//getting current profile
export const getProfile=()=>dispatch=>{
    //dispatching loading state before req
    dispatch(profileLoading());
    axios.get('/api/userprofile')
    .then(res=>
    dispatch({
        type:GET_USERPROFILE,
        payload:res.data
    }))
    .catch(err=>
    dispatch({
        type:GET_USERPROFILE,
        payload:{}
    }))
}


 // Create Profile
export const createProfile = (profileData, history) => dispatch => {
    axios
      .post('/api/userprofile', profileData)
      .then(res => history.push('/dashboard'))
      .catch(err =>
        dispatch({
          type: GET_ERRORS,
          payload: err.response.data
        })
      );
  };
  export const addExp=(experienceData,history)=>dispatch=>{
      axios.post('/api/userprofile/experience',experienceData)
      .then(res=>history.push('/dashboard'))
      .catch(err=>dispatch({
          type:GET_ERRORS,
          payload:err.response.data
      }))
  }

  export const deleteExperience = id => dispatch => {
    axios
      .delete(`/api/userprofile/experience/${id}`)
      .then(res =>
        dispatch({
          type: GET_USERPROFILE,
          payload: res.data
        })
      )
      .catch(err =>
        dispatch({
          type: GET_ERRORS,
          payload: err.response.data
        })
      );
  };
//loading the profile
export const profileLoading=()=>{
    return{
        type:PROFILE_LOADING
    }
}
//clearing profile
export const clearcurrentprofile=()=>{
    return{
        type:CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE
    }
}

//getting profiles
export const getProfiles = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(profileLoading());
    axios
      .get('/api/userprofile/all')
      .then(res =>
        dispatch({
          type: GET_PROFILES,
          payload: res.data
        })
      )
      .catch(err =>
        dispatch({
          type: GET_PROFILES,
          payload: null
        })
      );
  };

  //getting profile by profile name
  export const getProfileByName = profilename => dispatch => {
    dispatch(profileLoading());
    axios
      .get(`/api/profile/handle/${profilename}`)
      .then(res =>
        dispatch({
          type: GET_USERPROFILE,
          payload: res.data
        })
      )
      .catch(err =>
        dispatch({
          type: GET_USERPROFILE,
          payload: null
        })
      );
  };
```

Comment: its probably because `(profile === null || loading)` is true, figure out which one and fix it

Comment: Too much code. Can you trim this down to a [mcve] please? You may also want to take the [tour].

Comment: @EricHasselbring This will be true always until it fetches the data from profileContent.

Comment: if thats true, then there has to be an error or it is working properly